Autovacuum unable to vacuum which is causing DB reastart of Aurora Postgres DB
(Moved question from stackoverflow to dba.stackexchange)
I am using AWS Aurora Postgres 13.8. Now we have around 35-40 replication slots in DB and we dropped few replication slots. The reason for dropping was we were seeing restart of DB. CPU, Memory and Write/Read IOPS are normal. We are currently on db.r6i.24xlarge. We have verified that there are no long running transactions and no blocked pids
We dropped around 12(First 7 and then 5) replication slot in DB. xmin horizon is increasing and is not completely able to vacuum table. Below is from logs
First, we dropped 7 slots, logs after that were like
   2024-10-03 14:20:19 UTC::@:[17441]:LOG: automatic vacuum of table "<db_name>.pg_catalog.pg_statistic": index scans: 0
    pages: 0 removed, 4175180 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 649889 skipped frozen
    tuples: 0 removed, 63044551 remain, 62974732 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 850469227 
    buffer usage: 7064601 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
    avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
    system usage: CPU: user: 9.86 s, system: 0.02 s, elapsed: 50.84 s
    WAL usage: 0 records, 0 full page images, 0 bytes

Then we dropped 5 more slots, logs were then like:-
2024-10-03 17:02:12 UTC::@:[77466]:LOG: automatic vacuum of table "<dbname>.pg_catalog.pg_statistic": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 4175180 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 2299157 skipped frozen
tuples: 0 removed, 33025155 remain, 32953376 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 883545046
buffer usage: 3757715 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 4.93 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 15.72 s
WAL usage: 0 records, 0 full page images, 0 bytes

I do understand that no. of dead tuples have been cleaned significantly but how many more replication slot do we need to drop  in order to remove this error.
Also we have started seeing below error in logs now apart from above error.
024-10-04 07:03:15 UTC::@:[32040]:LOG: automatic vacuum of table "<dbname>.<schema>.<app_table_name>": index scans: 1
pages: 0 removed, 5949 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 557 skipped frozen
tuples: 5485 removed, 79016 remain, 0 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 903322403
buffer usage: 3757819 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 2.03 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 13.15 s
WAL usage: 0 records, 0 full page images, 0 bytes

As per the latest comment by Laurenz Albe in stack overflow, I was asked to to drop all stale replication slots (where restart_lsn in pg_replication_slots is old)
I ran this query
select slot_name, active, catalog_xmin, restart_lsn, pg_current_wal_insert_lsn()-restart_lsn as diff_lsn from pg_replication_slots order by diff_lsn desc; 

First 2 slots have a huge difference with diff_lsn 793117723072, 427503896816 and then all slots with 92440376. I understand that first 2 definitely needs to be deleted. However what about the remaining since their difference is also huge.
Also how can I prevent such scenarios in future.

None of the things you report as error are really errors.  Those are just non-error log messages. Do you log files show errors?  What are they?  What is the reason for the restarts?

You should drop every slot which does not have a reason to exist.  Why do all of these slots exist?

@jjanes - All replication slot which exists now are required. Inactive ones have either been dropped or have been made active. I understand its not the error but why is it not able to clean up dead tuples. This might create issue once it piles up. I also see replication slot lag is decreasing.

Currently the oldest replicationslotlag is around 500Gb, is it possible that once slot lag is decreased, this will start clearing it up?

Catalog tables (which includes pg_statistic) keep historical tuples around for use in reconstructing the metadata for objects being replicated for logical replication.  I don't know that this is actually necessary in the special case of pg_statistic, but anyway that is how it currently works.  So the vacuuming of catalog tables is hindered more than it is for normal tables.
You can check pg_replication_slots.catalog_xmin to see how far back each slot is holding the catalog (and therefore which slots might need to be dropped or prioritized for advancement), but I don't know how to figure out how far the slot needs to advance before catalog_xmin can advance.
Needless to say, the way to prevent reoccurrences is not to allow logical replication to fall behind by extravagant amounts in the first place.

Apart from restart_lsn, it is also interesting to look at the active column of pg_replication_slots. If a slot is not active, that means the the standby is not connected. Such slots will become a problem sooner or later.
There is also the difference between logical and physical replication slots (see the slot_type column). Streaming replication, which uses physical replication slots, usually consumes the information right away (it is written to the WAL on the standby), so replication slots usually don't lag for long.
But with logical decoding, the standby has to actively consume the information for restart_lsn to move forward. So with logical decoding, the problem may be on the consumer side. Also, logical decoding might be waiting for a long running transaction on the publisher to finish before the information can be decoded and sent and the replication slot can be moved forward.
So what I would do is: definitely drop the very old replication slots. Then see if VACUUM can clean up well enough now. If yes, don't worry: a few dead tuples that cannot yet be removed won't kill you. If it is a problem for VACUUM, and you have logical replication slots, investigate if you have long running transactions and check how the consumer is doing.
Disclaimer: from what I heard, the closed-source Aurora is heavily modified from normal PostgreSQL, and I have no access to the source. So you could also be facing Amazon problems. In particular, what you say about the database restarting doesn't sound familiar to me at all.

Thanks for your insights. We are using logical replication. To walk you more on the problem, the problem started when we saw sudden spike in write IOPS(1.4m/sec) and at that moment Memory was going down to less than 10% and was frequently restarting the DB. We managed to control writes by bringing it down to 600k/sec. The restart problem didn't completely eliminate but yes it was way lesser. Upon checking logs we could see significant amount of dead tuples not getting cleared through autovacuum.

So we started clearing inactive replication slots. DB is stable as of now with no restart observed in last 2 days however the logs still scares me as its not able to remove dead tuples completely. Do I still need to worry about it as it can pile up and might again cause issue in DB.

You should investigate these restarts, no clue about them. I would monitor the replication slots.
